# Automatically reindent lines filtered through formatprg

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, formatting

I have following xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <edge id="e6" source="n5" target="n4"> <data key="d1">1.1</data> <data key="d2">1.1</data> </edge>
</graph>
```

I have reconfigured `formatprg` for xml in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim`:

```
setlocal formatprg=tidy\ -xml\ -quiet\ --indent\ auto\ --tidy-mark\ no\ --indent-spaces\ 2\ --vertical-space\ yes\
```

When I now press `gqq` on line 3, I get

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
<edge id="e6" source="n5" target="n4">
  <data key="d1">1.1</data>
  <data key="d2">1.1</data>
</edge>
</graph>
```

I want to fix the indentation automatically.

My first try was `:'[,']norm =` which does not work as expected.

However, `=at` does.

Ideally, I want to extend `gq<text object/motion>` and `gqq` so re-indentation (`=`, `indentexpr`) is done on the newly formatted lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Linewise `gqq` with support for counts

I have come up with following solution for the linewise operator `gqq` by putting

```viml
nnoremap <buffer> gqq gqq$='[
```

into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim` (the `$` was important). Counts work already:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <edge id="e6" source="n5" target="n4"> <data key="d1">1.1</data> <data key="d2">1.1</data> </edge>
    <edge id="e7" source="n3" target="n4"> <data key="d1">1.1</data> <data key="d2">1.1</data> </edge>
</graph>
```

Again cursor on line 3 and then press `2gqq`. The result is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <edge id="e6" source="n5" target="n4">
        <data key="d1">1.1</data>
        <data key="d2">1.1</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e7" source="n3" target="n4">
        <data key="d1">1.1</data>
        <data key="d2">1.1</data>
    </edge>
</graph>
```

#### [Vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) re-mappings of `gq<text object/motion>` and `{VISUAL}gq`

Install the plugin [vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) and put

```viml
map <buffer> gq <Plug>(operator-myformat)
call operator#user#define('myformat', 'Op_format_and_reindent')
function! Op_format_and_reindent(motion_wiseness)
  exe "normal! '[V']gq$='["
endfunction
```

into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim`.

This should also work for other files with a `'formatprg'` and the desire to reindent automatically afterwards.