# Replace all self-closing xml tags with open and close tags

Tags: substitute, filetype-xml

I have an XML document with many (dozens) of the following tags:

```
<item prop1="val1" prop2="val2" />
```

I would like to change this to:

```
<item prop1="val1" prop2="val2">
   <sometihng>text</something>
</item>
```

However, I cannot even figure out how to change the self-cosing "item" tag into an open + close tag.  Further complicating this is the fact that each "item" tag may have a different number of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following substitution command:

```
:%s%<item[^>]\{-}\zs */>\ze%></item>%g
```

In this case I use `%` as separator instead of `/`. That way I need less escaping.

To explain the regex:

- `<item[^>]\{-}` matches `<item` followed by any number of characters, that are not `>`. The `\{-}` matches 0 or more, but as few as possible.
- `\zs */>\ze`: This matches the end of the tag with possible whitespaces. The interesting part it `\zs` and `\ze`. This defines the part of the match that should be replaced. Everything matched before `\zs` is left unchanged.

In words: Replace the `/>` of an "item" tag with `></item>`.

If you want a line break between opening and closing tag, use:

```
:%s%\(\s*\)<item[^>]\{-}\zs */>\ze%>\r\1</item>%g
```

This time the leading `\(\s*\)` matches the leading whitespaces and `\r\1` inserts the leading whitespaces after the line break. So indent is kept.

BTW: This only works, when self-closing tag is on one line.

To replace *any* self closing tag, you could use this:

```
:%s%\(\s*\)<\([-A-Za-z0-9_\.]*\)[^>]\{-}\zs */>\ze%>\r\1</\2>%g
```

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some more research I came up with something that is able to do this:

```
:%s/<item \(.*\)\/>/<item \1 >\r\t<something>text<\/something>\r<\/item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like (untested)

```
qq0f<lyiwf>F/i><Enter><<Esc>pq
```

Where `<Enter>` and `<Esc>` should be the keys Enter and Esc on your keyboard.

This should record a macro that does the transformation. It assumes the whole tag is on one line.

Theoretically, you could then follow with

```
g/<.*\\>/normal! @q
```

To transform the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Plugin [Emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim)

The plugin emmet provides the mapping `<C-y>j` to split or join tags. The help section explains what emmet does when using this mapping:

```
12. Split/join tag                             *emmet-split-join-tag* *<C-y>j*

  To join block, type '<C-y>j'.
>
  <div class="foo">
      cursor is here
  </div>
<
  Type '<C-y>j' in insert mode. Then,
>
  <div class="foo" />
<
  And type '<C-y>j' in there again.
>
  <div class="foo">
  </div>
```

Sometimes you have to modify many tags individually because you have to insert different content between the tags which makes a global substitution not perfect. However, a global substitution could still be the first step.

Following steps achieve the change described in the question:

1. Modify single tag

   1. `/<item` to move to tag `<item ... />`
   2. `<C-y>j` (`:h emmet-split-join`)
   3. `cit` (`:h it`)
   4. `something<C-y>;`  (`:h emmet-expand-word`)
   5. `text specific for this line<Esc>`
   6. `n` jump to next `<item` which should be changed
2. Modify all lines and insert the same text everywhere

   In this case I would use the `:substitute` command similar to [you](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19093/1292). However, I want to show that it is also be possible to use the plugin in combination with `:global` and `:normal` (or with a macro not shown here). I assume that all `<item .../>` are placed on separate lines

   ```
   :g/item/exec "norm f<\<C-y>jcitsomething\<C-y>;text"
   ```

**Formatting**

To format your xml source code, you can consider using `tidy` for `formatprg` by placing following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim`:

```
setlocal formatprg=tidy\ -xml\ -quiet\ --indent\ auto\ --tidy-mark\ no\ --indent-spaces\ 2\ --vertical-space\ yes
```

Now you can format the whole xml file afterwards with `gggqG`.

Furthermore, if you like to combine `formatprg=tidy ...` with `indentexpr=XmlIndentGet(v:lnum,1)` from `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/xml.vim`, have a look at following question [Automatically reindent lines filtered through formatprg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17996/automatically-reindent-lines-filtered-through-formatprg).

Answer (score 0):

#### Plugins [*Switch*](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/switch.vim) & [*SplitJoin*](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) by Andrew Radev

Install the two plugins and add following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim` for *switch.vim*:

```
let b:switch_custom_definitions =
      \ [
      \   {
      \     '<\(\S*\) \(.*\)\s*/>': '<\1 \2></\1>',
      \     '<\(\S*\) \(.*\S\)\s*>.*</\1>': '<\1 \2 />',
      \   },
      \ ]
```

Additionally, you could install [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) or [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) to add more easily the tag `something` with `ysiwt`+`something`.

Again, this answer targets the situation where it is more suitable to change individual tags:

1. `/<item` to move to first `<item`
2. `gs` from `switch.vim` to toggle tag between `<item .../>` and `<item ...></item>`
   (check toggle by pressing `gsgsgs`)
3. `gS` from `splitjoin.vim` to change from a single line to multi-line format
4. `o` to insert a new line below with the correct indentation
5. `your text<Esc>`
6. `ysiwt`+`something<CR>` surround your text with a tag with the help of `vim-surround`
7. `n` jump to next `<item` which should be changed